# How to compare Choice filed with multiple values and get result from sharepointList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

i am new to sharepoint.
i have two Sharepoint Lists `CustomerList` and `AnnouncementList`

```
CustomerList with columns(custid,name,region)
AnnoucementList with columns(Annid,AnnouncementText,region)
```

Now i want to display the Announcements to customers having 
CustomerList.region=AnnouncementList.region

Problem is the region is Choice field having multiple values

Eg.

```
Custid     name     region
     1     Shekhar  mumbai,pune

Annid  AnnouncementText  region
  1    Today is holiday  pune,gujrat
```

**Now, how to compare each Choice region from CustomerList 
with each Choice of AnnouncementList?** `using CAMEL QUERY`

Help appreciated!Even if one match found it must show the data.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To compare multi choice value in sharepoint list use SPMultiChoice Class for getting your result instead CAML query.